# Insert ACF field into shortcode

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I created a custom post type in Wordpress, which incorporates the ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin. I'm trying to find a way to get an ACF category / taxonomy field to automatically populate into a shortcode.

Here's the coding I have so far:

```
<?php 
$documents_cat= get_field("category");
$documents_shortcode = '[Documents category="'.$documents_cat.'"]';
$documents_to_string = strval($documents_shortcode);
echo do_shortcode($documents_to_string);
?>
```

The shortcode works, but pulls all of the categories and not the one specified in the ACF field called "category"

I may not have to use the ACF field, but could use the custom post types category / taxonomy, but not sure how to get it to work. I tried the following, but it didn't work at all:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[Documents category="'.the_category(','.'"]'); ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Additional note, the custom post type could have multiple categories, so I need to make sure the shortcode includes any category the post is assigned to.

UPDATE: Ok so I think I may have figured it out with the following code:

```
    <?php
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    $catname = $category->term_id;
    echo do_shortcode('[Documents category="' . $catname .'"]'); 
    } ?>
```

The ACF get_field function wasn't working as that field is the post's taxonomy, so it's not a field where information is entered.

Comment: Ok so I partially figured it out